# Interpolation within ode45

Tags: matlab, ode

I have a vector with discrete values that I need to pass into my ODE system and I want to use ode45 command. This vector needs to be interpolated within the solver when I use it. Is there a way this can be done?

I have a coupled system of linear ODEs.

```
dxdt = f(t)*x + g(t)*y
dydt = g(t)*x + h(t)*y
```

I have three vectors f(t), g(t) and h(t) as a function of t. I need to pass them into the the solver.

I can code up a Runge-Kutta solver in C or C++. I was suggested that doing it in Matlab would be quicker. Can someone suggest a way to do this?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html). Suppose you have vectors `fvec`, `gvec` and `tvec` containing respectively the values of f, g, and the time points at which these values are taken, you can define your derivative function as:

```
dxydt = @(t,x) [interp1(tvec, fvec, t) * x(1) + interp1(tvec, gvec, t) * x(2)
                interp1(tvec, gvec, t) * x(1) + interp1(tvec, hvec, t) * x(2)];
```

and use it in [`ode45`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html):

```
[T,Y] = ode45(dxydt, tspan, [x0; y0]);
```

Comment: Hi @Simon, why do we need interpolation if we know the exact form of time dependent parameters?

Comment: Hi @Simon can `tvec = tspan`?

Comment: @kww Yes, but you still need interpolation because the ode solvers use their own time discretization

Comment: @Simon Thanks. Can you give me some hints on solving Time dependent Schrodinger equation in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37981618/solving-time-dependent-schrodinger-equation-using-matlab-ode45