# Solving time-dependent Schrodinger equation using MATLAB ode45

Tags: matlab, matrix

The Schrodinger equation for a time-dependent Hamiltonian is:

[image: $$i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}\psi(t) = H(t)\psi(t) \, .$$]

I try to implement a solver for the Schrodinger equation for a time-dependent Hamiltonian in `ode45`. However, because the Hamiltonian $H(t)$ is dependent on time. I do not know how to do interpolation in `ode45`. Can you give me some hints?

```
psi0 = [0 1];
H = [1 0;0 1]*cos(t); %this is wrong, I do not know how to implement this and pass it to ode45
hbar = 1;
t    = [0:1:100];
[T, psi] = ode45(dpsi, t, psi);
function dpsi = f(t, psi, H, psi0)
dpsi = (1/i)*H*psi;
```

I also try to come up with a solution of matrix interpolation in 
[MATLAB: Interpolation that involve a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966770/matlab-interpolation-that-involve-a-matrix/37966882?noredirect=1#comment63388959_37966882).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`H` is just an identity matrix in your case, so we can just multiply it with the `psi` vector to get back the `psi` vector itself. Then, we bring `i*hbar` to the right-hand-side of the equation so that the final equation is in a form that `ode45` accepts. Finally, we use the following code to solve for `psi`:

```
function schrodinger_equation

  psi0 = [0;1];
  hbar = 1;
  t = [0 100];
  [T,psi] = ode45(@(t,psi)dpsi(t,psi,hbar),t,psi0);

  for i = 1:length(psi0)
    figure
    plot(T,real(psi(:,i)),T,imag(psi(:,i)))
    xlabel('t')
    ylabel('Re(\psi) or Im(\psi)')
    title(['\psi_0 = ' num2str(psi0(i))])
    legend('Re(\psi)','Im(\psi)','Location','best')
  end

end

function rhs = dpsi(t,psi,hbar)
  rhs = 1/(1i*hbar)*cos(t).*ones(2,1);
end
```

Note that I have plotted the two components of `psi` separately and for each such plot, I have also plotted the real and imaginary components separately. Here are the plots for two different values of `psi0`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this mean you do not have to do interpolation in the ode45? Does the $cos(t)$ term vary inside ode45?

Comment: The `cos(t)` term is certainly accounted for as you can see in the `dpsi` function.

Comment: Thanks. What if my time dependence is not so simple so that `H` cannot be represented like a identity matrix? What should I do? For example `H = [t 1;3t t^2]`?

Comment: The most direct way I can think of is to multiply `H` with the `psi` vector and assign the components of the result to `rhs` in the `dpsi` function.

Comment: That may work. So do I just pass each component into ode45 then ode45 can understand the time-dependence without doing interpolation?

Comment: Yeah. If you have a specific example, we can discuss in chat to avoid writing too many comments here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115575/discussion-between-kww-and-edwinksl).

Comment: By the way, please do accept the answer if it helped you so that people who might have a similar problem know the answer worked.